# Setting global pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using an external library that has some logging and you can change the log directory,

external_library.hpp

```
extern char const* _log;
```

external_library.cpp

```
char const* _log = "path_to_log.log";
```

In my own project I have:

settings.cpp

```
#include "external_library.hpp"
void set_log_path() {
 std::string _p = "new_path_log.log";
 char const* _log = _p.c_str();
}
```

and I'm looking to simply change the log path, what I have does not work but it does not give any errors either and if I do:

```
#include "external_library.hpp"
void set_log_path() {
 std::string _p = "new_path_log.log";
 _log = _p.c_str();
}
```

I get `_log is undefined` or:

```
#include "external_library.hpp"
char const* _log;
void set_log_path() {
 std::string _p = "new_path_log.log";
 _log = _p.c_str();
}
```

gives me:

```
1>external_library.lib(assert.obj) : error LNK2005: "char const * const _log" (?external_library_assert_log@@3PEBDEB) already defined in _functions.obj
```

How is it I do this properly?

Comment: What you're trying to do with first `std::string _p = "new_path_log.log";` followed by `_log = _p.c_str();` is *bad*. The variable `_p` will go out of scope when the function ends, and will therefore be destructed. That leaves you with `_log` pointing to something which does not exist any more. Is there a reason you want `_log` to be a pointer instead of a `std::string`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your approach is that the value returned by `_p.c_str()` becomes invalid as soon as `set_log_path` exits. This is because the C string is owned by `std::string` that gets destroyed.

Since header file `external_library` declares `_log` with `extern` keyword, this should work:

```
#include "external_library.hpp"
void set_log_path() {
   _log = "new_path_log.log";
}
```

If you need to construct log path dynamically, make a static `char[]` buffer of suitable size, format the path into it, and set `_log` to point to that buffer.

Alternatively, you could make your `std::string _p` static in the function to avoid the destructor call upon exiting the function.

Comment: Instead of making a static `char[]` buffer, why not make a static `std::string` and refer to that?

Comment: I thought it would be as simple as that but _log is undeclared identifier even though its part of the include.

Comment: @778899 There must be something else in your code preventing the inclusion, e.g. an incorrect inclusion guard. This should absolutely work. Although you could work around this by copy-pasting the `extern` declaration into your own code above `set_log_path` function, you need to figure out the inclusion issue anyway. Make sure you link with the external library, too.